# How to get parts of a frame in beamer to appear first on the bottom of the page?

Tags: beamer, pause

In `beamer`, I want to use `\pause` commands with an `\only` command. The latter should have material that appears *below* the material using `\pause`, but starting *before* the material using pause. I tried variants of the following, none of which worked:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \pause
Second 
   \pause
Third 

\only<1-3>{First-Third}
   \pause
Fourth 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I do not want to use `\item`; the material I will use is actually a paragraph broken into small parts to be revealed one at a time.

Comment: It is not clear (for me) what you want but let me tell you that there is `\onslide<>{}`  and `\uncover<>{}` commands.

Comment: This piece of code could help you to discover yourself how to get what you wish: `\onslide<2>{Second} \onslide<3>{Third} \onslide<1-3>{First-Third} \onslide<4->{Fourth}`

Comment: @Sigur Your code works as I want the result to appear. But is there no way to do it with `\pause`?

Comment: I think not since you want to jump in timeline, I mean, order of appearance doesn't match slides order.

Comment: @Sigur Yet such things are standard with `\item`, so I don't think the change of order can be the complete explanation.

Comment: Besides being easier to type, another benefit of using `\pause` is that it does not require grouping for input, which can conflict with other grouping used in an equation, for example.

Comment: Usually I don't use `pause` since it only works to *pause* the natural sequence of slides. It is not powerful.